# Use environment variable for Unit testing WCF services with AspNetDevelopmentServerAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, unit-testing

I am trying to launch an AspNetDevelopmentService during unit tests and I found [AspNetDevelopmentServerAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.web.aspnetdevelopmentserverattribute.aspx) that can be used [this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243136%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

It works just fine:

```
[AspNetDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:49409/", @"C:\Projects\WcfTestPlatform1\Bench.Services")]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var channel = new ChannelFactory<IMyContract>("*").CreateChannel();
    var result = channel.SayHello("Titi");

    Assert.AreEqual("Hello Titi", result);
}
```

As the msdn said, environment variables can be used in the service path. So I tried such a path: `[AspNetDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:49409/", @"%SolutionDir%Bench.Services")]`, but this didn't worked...

**Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here: set a service path relative to the solution?**......

Thanks!

**Edit 1**:
I tried the `%PathToWebRoot%` variable: `[AspNetDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:49409/", @"%PathToWebRoot%")]`: It works fine, but it doesn't replace a SolutionDir relative path. So I'll use it for now. 
Please do not hesitate if somebody know any other way that could be equivalent to what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried ${SolutionDir} instead of %SolutionDir% ?

Comment: Thanks Roy. It is a great idea and was actually my initial try until I saw the sample on the msdn formatting the variable with %xx%. It didn't work by the way :-)